# Sorting array A in o(nlogn)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Given array A of integers of length n. sort A in (small o) o(nlogn) when in the sorted array A ,every two consecutive elements differ by either k1,k2,k3 where k1,k2,k3

are different natural numbers.

I am having a problem solving this question, i tried finding the minimum on A
and making three new arrays each starts with min{A} of length n, forming a arithmetic sequence in each array using k1,k2,k3. merging the results and removing duplicated copies of each element and finally cutting all elements after max{A} in the new sorted array of length 3n. all operations are O(n)

.

the problem is this doesn't work when the difference between max{A}−min{A}
is not divisible by any k1,k2,k3

.

any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Create a directed graph with the numbers in the array as nodes. For each number `x`, if any of `x + k1,k2,k3` exist, add a directed edge.
Now do a simple topological sort.

Topological sorting takes `O(V + E)` time. Here, `V = n` and `E <= 3 * n`. So, the time for topological sorting is `O(n)`. Checking the existence of `x+k1,k2,k3` can also be done in linear time using a hash table.

Overall time complexity: `O(n)`.

Another way to solve the problem:

Find the smallest number in the array. Let the number be x. This is the first element of the sorted array. Now, check if `x+k1`, `x+k2` or `x+k3` exist in the array. At least one of then must exist in the array according to the given condition. The smallest of these is the second element of the sorted array. Repeat these steps until you are out of elements.

Each step requires `3` existence queries and there are `n` steps. With a hash table, the algorithm will be linear.

Comment: @user3386109. Yes. But the default sorting algorithms are O(nlogn). The questioner is asking whether something better is possibe if the condition regarding k1,k2 and k3 is true for the final sorted array.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear in the question itself, but it does seem like a reasonable interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear to me and as I can't comment for clarification, I am assuming two cases and answering both scenarios.

**Scenario 1:** In your question, **Sorted** means what we understand sorting is ( ascending or descending):

In that case, you have nothing to do without checking if the consecutive elements have the difference of k1, k2 or k3.

**Scenario 2:** In your question, **Sorted** means rearranging the given array elements in a way so that the difference between consecutive elements are k1, k2 or k3.

Example:
Input: [1, 2, 4, 5, 10], k1: 1, k2: 3, k3: 6

Output: [1, 2, 5, 4, 10]

In that case, it's a **Hamiltonian path finding** problem and this problem can be solved using DFS. First, construct a graph from the given array. Graph construction logics are given below:

1. Each index is a node
2. Two index (i,j) is connected if abs(A[i]-A[j]) is k1, k2 or k3.

The next step is to find out a path of length N having all N nodes in the graph.

**Complexity of scenario 2:**

It's an NP-complete problem.

Comment: Finding a path of length n in a graph is equivalent to the Hamiltonian path problem and can't be solved in O(n).

Comment: @merlyn Yes, you are right. I have updated complexity section. Thanks.